# wxPython virtualenv python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, virtualenv

I am trying to migrate my projects from Python 2.7.12 to Python 3.5.2. (That is the right thing to do; isn't it?)

I do understand that  getting wxPython to work in virtualenv can be a problem, but it works fine on Python 2 if I use this command to create the environment:

```
virtualenv env --system-site-packages
```

For Python 3, I use:

```
virtualenv -p python3 env --system-site-packages
```

But (as expected) this doesn't pick up wxPython

wxPython is installed at:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

but, of course, in

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

There is no wxPython.

What do I need to do to use it in my Python 3 environment?

I have entered my virtualenv environment and ran:

```
pip install -U wxPython
```

as recommended [here](https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html), but I get all these [error messages](https://pastebin.com/HuM5fwNH)

Comment: You need to install wxpython phoenix (wxpython 4.x.x) https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html (Note installation references to `pip` should be `pip3` at least on my Linux box)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Inside a virtualenv it can be just `pip` because there is only 1 `pip`. Outside of virtualenv it must be `pip3`. Also I think your comment should be an answer for the OP to accept it.

Comment: I tried **pip install -U wxPython** from within the Python 3 environment, but if fails with a build error

Comment: Would you care to elucidate?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony See my edited Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear not to have `gtk3` installed on your system.
I made a similar mistake when I built the `gtk3` version of `wxpython` and expected it to look the same as `gtk2` it doesn't!
Either install `gtk3` or see this [Has wxpython SpinCtrl/SpinButton changed between Classic and Phoenix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510148/has-wxpython-spinctrl-spinbutton-changed-between-classic-and-phoenix)
which how I installed and built `wxpython 4.0.0b2` for `gtk2` on Linux (there's always a caveat)